# How to solve "identifier starts immediately after numeric literal"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried for following code in javascript, but I get:

```
identifier starts immediately after numeric literal
```

*error* is coming for following script, example `mcnDel="016160A1"`

```
<script>
 mcnDel="016160A1"               
 var val="<a href='javascript: void(0);' onclick='removeRow("+mcnDel+");'><img src=images/delete.png></a></a></td>"  
</script>
```

Comment: Are you inserting partial HTML elements, and do you really have an anchor inside an anchor ?

Comment: It is confusing why you have a `</a>` and `</td>` at the end of your string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to wrap the string with quotes.

```
onclick='removeRow("+mcnDel+");'
```

needs to be

```
onclick='removeRow(\""+mcnDel+"\");'
```

Answer (score 3):

FYI, I got that error while trying to use `BigInt()` and big integer litterals (e.g. `123n` on Safari for iOS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this was my issue as well. I solved it by using an external library such as https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js

Answer (score 1):

Dont forget Javascript id cannot start with a number, make sure the value of your variable is not starting with a number.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this answer maybe help another : when we want to concat or add something with a string in Js we must use single quotation. for example we have :

```
    alert(@ViewBag.IsSecondStepAccepted) === error :identifier starts immediately after numeric literal
```

but if I use

```
    alert('@ViewBag.IsSecondStepAccepted')
```

everything is OK.

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was in numeric literal with an underscore

```
1_000
```

after removing the underscore my code started to work