# Jquery adding extra characters to button

Tags: jquery

I want to generate a button like this :

```
    $("#card").append('<div><button onclick=" edit("'+k+'")" > Edition</button> my text <br></div>');
```

The html button generated by the previous code is this :

```
<button onclick=" edit(" 5b027d9110966772975cb2d4")"=""> Edition</button>
```

Please notice the bad ="" caracters, i don't know where the hell it comes from.

As long as i try this :

```
$("#card").append('<div><button onclick=" edit(12)" > Edition</button> my text <br></div>');
```

it is working.

Please help me, is this a jquery bug ?

MORE INFOS , this is my ajax complete code, my goal is to retrieve data from couchDb, then to display a clickable button for each document (object)

```
   $.ajax({
    url: remoteURL + '?' + 'skip='+ skip + '&' + 'limit=' + limit + '&include_docs=true',
   data: {format: 'json'},
   error: function() {
      $('#info').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
   },
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   success: function(data) {
      console.log(data.rows);
      var html = data.rows;
    for(x = 0;x<data.rows.length;x++){

        $("#card").append('<div><button onclick=" edit("'+data.rows[x].doc._id+'")" > Edition</button>  '+data.rows[x].doc.nom + '<br></div>');
    }
   },
   type: 'GET'
});
```

Then, all of my buttons are generated with the extra ="" caracters, so i can'"t click and get an error.
As long as i replace +data.rows[x].doc._id+ by an INT like 2 for example, it is working, i really can't understand why it is generating ="" characters !

Comment: why not bind the click using jquery?

Comment: it is in a for loop, for generating a lot of button

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem: http://jsbin.com/bubalef/edit?html,js,output

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/ - read the delegated event section

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#card").append('<div><button onclick="edit('+ "'" + data.rows[x].doc._id + "'" + ')" > Edition</button> my text <br></div>');
```

Try this code.

Comment: thanks a lot ! Ill try this, i cant express how much im gratefull

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found an answer there :

[How to solve "identifier starts immediately after numeric literal"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509317/how-to-solve-identifier-starts-immediately-after-numeric-literal)

it is working now, thanks a lot, hope to help if possible in the future !

Now this is my jquery function that is working ( Please notice the \""+k+"\" ) :

```
    var k = data.rows[x].doc._id ;      
    $("#card").append("<div><button onclick=' edit(\""+k+"\")' >Edition</button>my text <br></div>");
```